# How to create an evil-delete-previous-line command?

Tags: evil, defun

I am trying to create a command which deletes preceding whole lines, just like evil-delete-whole-line, but backwards.
So far I have the following

```
(evil-define-operator delete-previous-line
  (beg end type register yank-handler)
  "Delete whole line."
  :motion evil-line-or-visual-line

  (interactive "<R><x>")
  (evil-previous-line 1)

  (evil-delete-whole-line beg end type register yank-handler))
```

It does delete the previous line, but unfortunately doesn't respond to the count operator. That is if I press certain number before using the operator the behavior isn't the expected one. How can I have the behavior mentioned in the beginning?

Comment: Are you sure that this deletes the previous line? It does not work here (the `beg` and `end` are set when invoking the command). Also, the command must be defined using 'evil' tools? Or would it be fine to just create an Emacs command? Or maybe even a recorded keyboard macro, which would definitely be the fastest and simplest solution (although that counts deleting multiple lines as multiple edits for undo).

Comment: Evil command preferred, as I want it to be integrated in the evil ecosystem (e.g. yank goes into clipboard, the number written before the command executes it x times). Thanks, your answer does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you would like the command to behave exactly, but I suppose that you would like to include the `save-excursion`. Also, I am not sure if I do things correctly (how they are supposed to be used). But by inspecting the evil code, I came up with the following command, which seems to do the trick:

```lisp
(evil-define-operator delete-previous-line (beg end type register count yank-handler)
  "Delete preceding line(s)."
  :motion nil
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")
  (save-excursion
    (evil-previous-line 1)
    (setq end (or end (1+ (line-end-position))))
    (when count
      (evil-previous-line (1- count)))
    (setq beg (or beg (line-beginning-position)))
    (evil-delete beg end type register yank-handler)))
```